# PostgreSQL, delete values from a table that match the output of a query on the table the values are being deleted from

Tags: postgresql, sql-delete

I'm capturing data from a database each day, by running an insert statement using a query and the values for whatever the current date is when the query is run.

To stop the table from getting too large I want to remove any values where a combination of an "ID" and a "Status" is the same as on the previous day

My table has the structure:

|Date|Email|Status|

```
delete from table sct
using
(
select "Email", min("Date") as "First Date of Status", "Status" from table sct
group by "Email", "Status"
) as t1
where sct."Email" = t1."Email" and sct."Date" = t1."First Date of Status" and sct."Status" = t1."Status"
and t1."First Date of Status" is null
```

As I only want to capture the first date a status changes, I want to delete all rows where the value for "First Date of Status" is null

But when I run this statement none of the rows in the original table are deleted.

Any feedback on how to fix this statement or an alternative method of solving this probem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This problem might be easier to solve if you had a primary key column (e.g. `id`) that you could use to get a unique row number. Then you could use a CTE WITH clause to select the rows you want to delete. Something like `WITH a AS (SELECT id FROM sct WHERE.....); DELETE FROM TABLE sct WHERE id IN a.id`

Answer (score 0):

```
and sct."Date" = t1."First Date of Status" 
             and t1."First Date of Status" is null
```

This will never work. You need to understand three-valued logic. null = null returns unknown, not true.